# HIbernation or Suspending & Restarting for NON-root users

Tags: root, hibernate, programming, process, job-control

My purpose is to run a main shell script which calls many sub-processes like other shell scripts, perl sources, and compiled c++ files.

I want to run the main shell script "run.sh" at some line in the source file(e.g. line 100)  and want to save all data sets which is necessary to execute the other parts of "run.sh"(e.g. all lines greater than 100).

One of my concerns is global variable which these scripts and compiled c++ files contain.

I use ubuntu 14.04 and I do NOT have the root account.

So, I cannot use hibernate command or other tools for the root users.

> Is there a way to solve this situation?

If possible, I want to accomplish this task by modifying the "run.sh".